# Joomla component error in models file

Tags: php, joomla, web

I'm trying to develop a component for joomla (I'm a begginer) and receive this error:

`Parse error: syntax error, unexpected $end in /home/sharesaf/public_html/test/components/com_usersall/models/usersall.php on line 1` .

The thing is i don't have any unclosed brackets.

This is the code

```
<?php
defined('_JEXEC') or die();
jimport('joomla.application.component.model');

class UsersallModelUsersall extends JModel{

    function getUsers(){
        $db =& JFactory::getDBO();
        $query = 'SELECT id,username FROM l08sx_users';
        $db->setQuery($query);
        $users = $db->loadAssocList();
        return $users;
    }
}
?>
```

Can you please help me with this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you've posted is fine - the missing curly bracket must be in code that you've added/changed in other files related to the component.  Check your views such as view.html.php  (and probably default.php) and files in the controllers folder